# Can I do on-the-fly calculation on a column using data.table in r?

Tags: r, data.table, cumulative-sum, rolling-computation

Hi I am wondering if anyone knows/ could show me how to calculate a value in a column `C` based on the previous value(s) in this column `C` and another column `D` and save the calculated value as a new current value in column `C`?

For example, suppose I first initialize the column `C` to `1`s and the calculation I want to implement is `C(1) = 1 + B(1)*0.1*1` and `C(2) = C(1) + B(2)*0.1*C(1)`.

```
test=data.table(A=1:5,B=c(1,2,1,2,1),C=1)
test
   A B C
1: 1 1 1
2: 2 2 1
3: 3 1 1
4: 4 2 1
5: 5 1 1
```

What I want is:

```
test
   A B C
1: 1 1 1.1
2: 2 2 1.32
3: 3 1 1.452
4: 4 2 1.7424
5: 5 1 1.91664
```

I could achieve what I want with `for loop` or `apply()` but I really want to know if this is doable just using `data.table` and get some speed up.

### Edit:

As pointed out by Frank in the comments below,

```
test[, C := cumprod(1 + .1*B)]
```

will do since multiplication is distributive. What if I want to supply a more complex custom function?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your calculation right? C(1) = 1 + .1*B(1) = 1.1 seems right, but C2 = C(1) * [1 + .1*B(2)] = 1.1 * 1.2 = 1.32, not 1.2. Anyways, it should be reducible to `test[, v := cumprod(1 + .1*B)]`, right?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I did make a mistake here

Comment: Hi Frank, in this example since multiplication is distributive the operation can be reduced, but I am also curious about what if the operation contains more complex functions such as if clause or some custom function?

Comment: Yeah, if it's irreducibly recursive, then I think you have to use a loop. You can write it with Rcpp for a speed boost if needed. A lot of simple problems can be solved with pmin/pmax/cumprod/cumsum, though.

Answer (score 3):

Using the formula as presented we have:

```
test[, C := Reduce(function(c, b) c + .1 * b * c, B, init = 1, acc = TRUE)[-1] ]
```

Of course, as pointed out already it simplifies in this particular case since we can write the body of the function as `c * ( 1 + .1 * b)` which implies a cumulative product of the parenthesized portion.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to apply the function cumulatively

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

test=data.table(A=1:5,B=c(1,2,1,2,1),C=1)

z <- function(b){1+b*0.1}

test[,C:=cumprod(rollapply(B, width=1, FUN=z))]
```

But I agree that there's really no need to bring zoo here. Frank's solution is more elegant and concise.

```
test[,C:=cumprod(1 + .1*B)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a similar `data.table` function, but it seems like `accumulate` from `purrr` is what you want. Simple example below, but the input could be rows of a data.table also.

```
library(purrr)

accumulate(1:4, function(x, y){2*x + y})
# [1]  1  4 11 26
```